# React Native delete duplicate photos feature is it possible without being to complex?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, duplicates

hope you are all doing fantastic.

I'm working on a small mobile app, and it's going to be super simple, but wanted to add a feature and have not been able to figure out if it is possible without some super complex coding.

I would like to check the devices photos and look for duplicate photos. now I know there are a lot of apps that do that, but i would like to integrate it in my app.

The idea is to allow the user to delete those photos that always get duplicated, because you took the picture, then you sent it through whats app, then you friend stars a group and sends it back, or send it through an email and we always end up having multiple copies of it on our device all over the place.

Now I'm not so experience in React native and the only info I could find is that you can look into the devices photos, and then found a function to compare it by uri (not sure) but that will not do the trick right? the  an have diferent location and names.

is there a way of doing this without being to complicated and time consuming? Or how is this done?

Thank you in advance

happy coding